# Where to put JavaScript files in a Symfony2 project?

Tags: javascript, symfony

I have a Symfony2 project and I have some JavaScript code to be executed.

Where should the `.js` file be stored in the project and how to call this file (instead of putting the entire script in the `.twig`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in `web/js`, then access it in your html via:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

or consider using [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).

Comment: PS: One more question, I am getting an javascript error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined when I am trying to use $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: You need to import jQuery **before** you execute any other scripts requiring it.